# C# BestPractice: Private var and Public Getter/Setter or Public Var

Tags: c#

What are the advantages and differences between the below two coding styles...

```
public void HelloWorld () {

        private string _hello;

        public string Hello {    
           get
            {
                return _hello;
            }
           set
            {
                _hello = value;
            }
        }
}
```

or

```
public void HelloWorld () {

        public string Hello { get; set; }

}
```

My preference is for short simple code, but interested to hear opinions as I see many developers who insist on the long route.

Comment: I would suggest to change the title to something like *"What is the difference between manually implemented properties and auto properties"* or something like that. None of your code samples expose a public variable (or rather field, as it should be in this case).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first one allows you to customize the accessors. For instance, you might want to validate the value in the setter, or lazily load the value in the getter. It also allows you to make the backing field `readonly`.

The second form allows no customization (except accessibility of the getter and setter). It's just a shorthand equivalent of the first form.

If you don't need to do anything specific in the getter and setter, the second form is usually more convenient.

Answer (score 5):

Your second example is not a public variable, it's just an auto property. And an auto property is just syntactic sugar for your first example.

Far as advantages of one over the other go, the first way allows you to do extra work in the getter or setter (such as a check for null or a property change notification):

```
private string _name;
public string Hello {    
{
    get
    {
        if(_name == null)
            _name = "Default Name";

        return _name;
    }
    set
    {
        _name = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Unless you need to perform some initialization on the private backing field or need it for some other reason, the more concise auto-property is generally preferred.

So for your example, where nothing is being done with the backing field, I would always prefer to use the auto-property.

Answer (score 1):

In the following I'm assuming you don't have any other needs like validation / side-effects.

- Only the first works on earlier versions of c#
- Only the first allows a simple field-initialiser (rather than constructor)
- Only the first allows adding attributes to the *field* such, as `[NonSerialized]`
- Switching between the two can break some serializers (`BinaryFormatter` for example) and reflection-based code

But the `{get;set;}` is more concise, and preferred in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I know you can't debug auto properties.
See [link text](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/372537/auto-properties-cannot-be-debugged)

So, if you need a breakpoint on the getter / setter you will need the verbose form.

Answer (score 0):

The distinction that you are drawing here is between using an explicit variable to store a value for a property vs. using an auto-generated property variable.

There are a lot of things you can do with an explicit variable that you cannot do with an auto-generated property variable. You can initialize it in the field declairation rather than in the constructor. You can validate it. You can normalize it (like trimming the string, etc.).

But if you don’t need to do any of that, then the auto prop is just fine.